# How to use GUI reporting in python Hypothesis

Tags: user-interface, python-hypothesis, property-based-testing

As my hypothesis tests run, I want, for each test, to collect a few random examples that were used for that test, and demonstrate them via a gui. So for example if I have two tests `def test_a(a: int)` and `def test_b(b: str)`, then after it has finished testing all the examples for `test_a`, I want it to sample 5 random examples, create a gui window that visually represents those examples, blocks until I close the window, then continues on to `test_b`, where it does the same basic thing. Also, if an exception is caught during a test, the gui pops up immediately for that test based off the examples that have been seen so far.

I have awkwardly implemented this with `execute_example`, by having each test change an essentially global field `curDesc`, then `execute_example` checks whether or not that's equal to `lastDesc`, and if there's a change it shows the gui (which blocks). But this is ugly and has several problems, like there winds up being multiple attempts to produce the gui for a single test, and also the final test won't ever produce a gui this way:

```
179   # It adds the scenario returned by the test into a collection of scenarios
180   # to be used for a GUI demo, and displays some of the related scenarios whenever
181   # the test changes or an exception occurs.
182   def execute_example(self, fn):
183     def viewScens(viewDesc):   
184       scens = self.scenarios[viewDesc]
185       if scens:
186         numScens = min(NUM_VIZ, len(scens))
187         print(f"showing {numScens} '{viewDesc}' scenarios")
188         testGUI = TestGUI(random.sample(scens, numScens))
189         testGUI.run()

190     self.curDesc = None
191     self.curScen = None
192     try:
194       ret = fn()
196       if self.curDesc != self.lastDesc:
197         if self.curDesc in self.seenDescs:
198           # PROBLEM: this happens several times per test
199           print(f"'{self.curDesc}' has been seen before")
200         # PROBLEM: this won't ever be called for the last test!
201         viewScens(self.lastDesc)
202       return ret  
                                         
203     except Exception as e:
204       # UnsatisfiedAssumption is used to break out of an example where the preconditions aren't met
205       if not isinstance(e, UnsatisfiedAssumption):
206         print(f"exception with '{self.curDesc}'")
207         viewScens(self.curDesc)
208       raise e

209     finally:
210       self.seenDescs.add(self.curDesc)
211       if isinstance(self.curScen, TestScenario):
212         self.scenarios[self.curDesc].append(self.curScen)
213       self.lastDesc = self.curDesc
```

Surely there must be a better way?

Or failing that, is there some way to perform an action after all hypothesis tests have run? Or at least all tests in a specific class or file? Why is hypothesis running a bunch of examples for `test_a`, then resetting the state, then doing more examples for `test_a`? Note that the issue with seeing the same desc multiple times occurs when there is only one test! The only time `lastDesc` is set to `None` is in `__init__`, so for the `curDesc` to change more than once implies that the test class is being init'd multiple times just to test one test inside of it, which seems weird. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening here, and without a minimal reproducing example I don't think I'll be able to work it out.  I suggest trying with a test function instead of a class, to rule out possibilities unrelated to the GUI part of your question.

Comment: @ZacHatfield-Dodds Let me give a higher level description of what I want to do. I want to report about my tests, as the tests are running, but not via stdout. Perhaps, while `test_a` is being tested, I want to generate a GUI that shows what `test_a` is doing, or I want to write to a file that is being tail'd elsewhere. I want this to happen the same way for every test, so I don't want to have to write this code into every test. I tried a way to do this but it had issues, so I'm hoping you can suggest a better way.

Comment: @ZacHatfield-Dodds Oh I forgot to add - one of the reasons I can't just do this in a test is because I don't want the report to happen for every single example. If `test_a(int)` gets called with 100 example ints, I really only want to report a random sampling of 5 or something.

Comment: I suggest having the test send every example, and downsampling on the GUI side.  If you also drop the "block between tests" part which is not about Hypothesis at all, I think this should be reasonably simple to implement.

Comment: @ZacHatfield-Dodds is there any way to see when a certain test is about to be finished? Like the final example for `test_a` has just been tested, and hypothesis is about to move on to `test_b`? If I could just be aware somehow of the boundary between tests, this would solve most of my problems. Ideatlly i'd also be able to hold off on `test_b` executing until user input has been made that says i'm done looking at the report for `test_a`. Thanks!